# `Get-Volume` does not list system favorite volumes mounted by VeraCrypt

Tags: powershell, volumes, veracrypt

I have a Windows 10 Pro (v1903) machine setup with 2 SSDs and full disk encryption by VeraCrypt. The second SSD is mounted as a [system favorite volume](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Favorite%20Volumes.html), so that I only have to provide one password/key at boot and both SSDs will be mounted successfully.

In Windows Explorer, both SSDs are listed as *usual* with drive letters and everything looks fine. But in the *Disk Management* console, the second SSD is listed without a drive letter and as *RAW*.

Issuing `Get-Volume` in an elevated PowerShell (v5.1) will not list the second SSD even if I can see it in the Windows Explorer with a drive letter.

How can I *really* list all volumes using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the good old WMI is able to *really* list all volumes:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, Label, FileSystem, DriveType, FreeSpace, Capacity | Format-Table
```

or *newer*:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume | Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, Label, FileSystem, DriveType, FreeSpace, Capacity | Format-Table
```